# Spring cloud gateway ribbon retry issue

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, ribbon, spring-cloud-gateway

we are using spring cloud GW with eureka ,we have set **client.ribbon.MaxAutoRetriesNextServer=1** in application properties of spring cloud GW and spring retry jars are also there in classpath. Now if out of two instances one instance is shut down GW is not retrying request with next available sever.

But this configuration is working in case of one microservice to microservice communication. We have service1 which is calling service2 with restTemplate annoted with **@loadbalanced** using ribbon , in this case if one instance of service2 is down then service1 is able to user next available server.

So what is issue when we are using Ribbon with Spring cloud GW , is it related with Netty since I can see netty exception in GW logs?

Comment: @Abhijit Sarkar,@spencergibb,@Satya